Warning: Undefined array key "logo_max_width" in ..../footer.php on line 62 >
I am having this error and how do I fix this . The site use ACF for footer . It has a field for logo which I think causing the error .
Here is the line in which the error occur .
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="home-link" <?php if($footer['logo_max_width']) { echo 'style="max-width:' . $footer['logo_max_width'] . 'px;"'; } ?>><img src="<?=$footer['logo']['url']?>" alt="<?=$footer['logo']['alt']?>" /></a>

Thanks for any help .

This question is similar to: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can fix the issue by using isset() to check if the array key exists. We are accessing $footer['logo_max_width'], you should check if it exists using the isset() function ().
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" class="home-link" 
    <?php if (isset($footer['logo_max_width'])) { 
            echo 'style="max-width:' . esc_attr($footer['logo_max_width']) . 'px;"'; 
        }
    ?>>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($footer['logo']['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($footer['logo']['alt']); ?>" />
</a>

You can set a default value if you want to avoid missing keys If ACF is not providing the logo_max_width field value
$maxWidth = isset($footer['logo_max_width']) ? esc_attr($footer['logo_max_width']) : 200; // Default to 200px if not set

Please try this solution to solve problam

Where in the code should I insert that isset() ?
Thanks !

like this if (isset($footer['logo_max_width'])). isset() in $footer function

'<a href="" class="home-link"
>

'
Where exactly here ?

The first line of code is the same as copy and past then test
